# How to change a photo?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change photos in android studio by clicking on  my button.
When I put code for changing the photo  in my MainActivity.java I keep getting this type of error messages and it says : 
**Cannot resolve symbol "image"**

image.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxx);

I am watching Udemy course for android development and I have done everything same like the professor on that video.

I have tried to restart android studio.
I have tried to make new project.
I have tried to clear invalidate caches and restart.

```
public void changeImage(View view)
{
    ImageView bitcoin = findViewById(R.id.bitcoin);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxx);


}
```

I hope there is actual error with android studio,because code is clone of the video that I am watching.

Comment: `ImageView bitcoin` vs `image`. Change one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Set Your Code Like this

```
ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.bitcoin);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxx);
```

Comment: I've just reviewed one of your [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22153628). It should be noted that code formatting should be used for code, not for names such as iOS or Android, you can find more information here: [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right)

Answer (score 1):

You are binding your layout's ImageView in Java file with bitcoin variable and you are trying to set an image on an unknown variable 'image'(maybe it's not defined in the class). So you have to set as below.

`ImageView bitcoin = findViewById(R.id.bitcoin);
 bitcoin.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxx);`

Answer (score 0):

change your this line

`image.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxx)`

to this one:

`bitcoin.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxx)`